# DirectX11 How to write data to texture and read it in pixel shader?

Tags: c++, directx-11

I'm new to DirectX and I'm writing a program that displays dynamically changed a number of lights, and I want to pass lights data in Texture (I can't use constant buffer, because arrays size in constant buffer can't be changed) to my pixelshader.
I fill in the **XMFLOAT4 lightData** array with light info and then map it to my texture in the **updateLight** function. But when I try to sample it in my pixel shader only the first row of texture reads correctly that is I got the right Lights number, ambient color data, and attenuations, and other data seems to be just zero. First time I try to sample at coordinates at which I fill my array (0,0), (2, 0), etc, but then I understand, that textures map coordinates to the range [0, 1], so I simply divide array coordinates by texture size and this is doesn't help.

So the question is, which coordinates I should sample, or how I can map my array to specific coordinates?

### data description

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11SamplerState> samplerStateLightInfo;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> lightInfo;
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView> lightTexture;
XMFLOAT4 lightData[LIGHT_TEXTURE_HEIGHT][MAX_LIGHT_CNT];
```

### init and update light

```
// calls once
bool Graphics::initLight() {

    // Refer to CB_light.hlsli 
    // to read texture description

    DXGI_FORMAT texFormat = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;

    CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc(texFormat, MAX_LIGHT_CNT, LIGHT_TEXTURE_HEIGHT);
    texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    texDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    texDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    HRESULT hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, nullptr, lightInfo.GetAddressOf());
    ONFAILHRLOG(hr, "Can't create texture for light info.", false);

    CD3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC SRVDesc(D3D_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D, texFormat);
    hr = device->CreateShaderResourceView(lightInfo.Get(), &SRVDesc, lightTexture.GetAddressOf());
    ONFAILHRLOG(hr, "Can't create shader resource view for light texture", false);

    // Create sampler description for sampler state
    CD3D11_SAMPLER_DESC sampDesc(D3D11_DEFAULT);
    sampDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT;
    // Create sampler state
    hr = device->CreateSamplerState(&sampDesc, samplerStateLightInfo.GetAddressOf());
    COM_ERROR_IF_FAILED(hr, "Failed to create rasterizer state for lights.");

    return true;
}

// calls each frame
bool Graphics::updateLight() {

#ifdef ENABLE_IMGUI
    ImGui::Begin("Light Controls");
    ImGui::DragFloat3("Ambient light color", &lightData[0][1].x, 0.01, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    ImGui::DragFloat("Ambient light strength", &lightData[0][2].x, 0.01, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    ImGui::DragFloat("Dynamic light strength", &light.lightStrength, 0.01, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    ImGui::DragFloat("Dynamic light Attenuation A", &light.attenuation_a, 0.01, 0.1f, 1.0f);
    ImGui::DragFloat("Dynamic light Attenuation B", &light.attenuation_b, 0.01, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    ImGui::DragFloat("Dynamic light Attenuation C", &light.attenuation_c, 0.01, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    ImGui::InputInt("Light cnt", &lightsCnt);
    ImGui::End();
#endif

    std::wstring dls = std::to_wstring(light.lightStrength);
    dls = L"dls: " + dls + L"\n";
    OutputDebugStringW(dls.c_str());
    constraintInPlace(lightsCnt, 0, MAX_LIGHT_CNT);

    lightData[0][0].x = MAX_LIGHT_CNT;
    lightData[0][0].y = lightsCnt;
    lightData[0][3].x = light.attenuation_a;
    lightData[0][3].y = light.attenuation_b;
    lightData[0][3].z = light.attenuation_c;

    double time = globalTimer.getMillisecondsElapsed() / 10000;
    for (int i = 0; i < lightsCnt; i++) {
        lightData[2][i] = { 10 * static_cast<float>(sin(time * i * i)),
                            10 * static_cast<float>(cos(time * i * i)),
                            0.0, 0.0 };
        lightData[1][i].x = light.lightColor.x;
        lightData[1][i].y = light.lightColor.y;
        lightData[1][i].z = light.lightColor.z;
        lightData[1][i].w = light.lightStrength;
    }

    constexpr UINT mapFlags = 0;
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    ZeroMemory(&mappedResource, sizeof(mappedResource));
    HRESULT hr = deviceContext->Map(lightInfo.Get(), 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, mapFlags, &mappedResource);
    ONFAILHRLOG(hr, "Failed to map light texture buffer.", false);
    CopyMemory(mappedResource.pData, &lightData, sizeof(lightData));
    deviceContext->Unmap(lightInfo.Get(), mapFlags);
    return true;
}
```

My pixel shader now looks like this:

### Pixelshader.hlsl

```
#include "CB_light.hlsli"

struct PS_INPUT {
    float4 inPosition : SV_POSITION;
    float2 inTexCoord : TEXCOORD;
    float3 inNormal : NORMAL;
    float3 inWorldPosition : WORLD_POSITION;
};

Texture2D objTexture : Texture : register(t0);
SamplerState objSamplerState : Sampler : register(s0);

float4 main(PS_INPUT input) : SV_TARGET {
    float3 sampleColor = objTexture.Sample(objSamplerState, input.inTexCoord);   
    float3 color = calculateColor(sampleColor, input.inNormal, input.inWorldPosition, lightSource);
    return float4(color, 1.0f);
}
```

### CB_light.hlsli

```
// per object buffers
cbuffer light_object : register(b1) {
    bool lightSource;
}

// texture size is 3 * lightsCnt
// zero row: TextureWidth(max lights cnt) +  lightsCnt, ambientLightColor, ambientLightStrength, attenuations
// first row: dynamicLightColor + Strength
// second row: dynamicLightPosition
// Bind this to 10'th registers to avoid intersections
// TODO: figure out how to fix bindings
Texture2D lightInfo: Texture : register(t10);
SamplerState lightSampler : Sampler : register(s10);

float2 getTextCoords(float y, float x, float width, float height = 3) {
    // return coords in range [0, 1]
    return float2(x / width, y / height);
}
    
float3 calculateColor(float3 sampleColor, float3 normal, float3 position, bool lightSource=false) {

    const float MAX_LIGHTS_CNT = lightInfo.Sample(lightSampler, float2(0, 0)).x; // texture width
    int lightsCnt = lightInfo.Sample(lightSampler, float2(0, 0)).y;
    float3 ambientLightColor = lightInfo.Sample(lightSampler, getTextCoords(0, 1, MAX_LIGHTS_CNT)).rgb;
    float ambientLightStrength = lightInfo.Sample(lightSampler, getTextCoords(0, 2, MAX_LIGHTS_CNT)).x;
    float3 attenuations = lightInfo.Sample(lightSampler, getTextCoords(0, 3, MAX_LIGHTS_CNT)).xyz;
    float dynamicLightAttenuation_a = attenuations.x;
    float dynamicLightAttenuation_b = attenuations.y;
    float dynamicLightAttenuation_c = attenuations.z;

    float3 ambientLight = ambientLightColor * ambientLightStrength;
    float3 appliedLight = ambientLight;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < lightsCnt; i++) {  
        
        float4 dynamicLightSC = lightInfo.Sample(lightSampler, getTextCoords(1, i, MAX_LIGHTS_CNT));
        float3 dynamicLightColor = dynamicLightSC.xyz;
        float dynamicLightStrength = dynamicLightSC.w;
        float3 dynamicLightPosition = lightInfo.Sample(lightSampler, getTextCoords(2, i, MAX_LIGHTS_CNT)).xyz;
        
        float3 diffuseLightIntensity;
        float distanceToLight;
        if (lightSource) {
            distanceToLight = 1;
            diffuseLightIntensity = normalize(float3(1, 1, 1));
        }
        else {
            float3 vectorToLight = normalize(dynamicLightPosition - position);
            // we don't lightning objects that are opposite to our light source,
            // but we don't want to make it darker too
            diffuseLightIntensity = max(dot(vectorToLight, normal), 0);
            distanceToLight = distance(dynamicLightPosition, position);
        }
    
        float attenuationFactor = 1.0 / (dynamicLightAttenuation_a +
                                         dynamicLightAttenuation_b * distanceToLight +
                                         dynamicLightAttenuation_c * pow(distanceToLight, 2));
       
        diffuseLightIntensity *= attenuationFactor;

        float3 diffuseLight = diffuseLightIntensity * dynamicLightStrength * dynamicLightColor;
        
        appliedLight += diffuseLight;
    }
    
    float3 finalColor = appliedLight * sampleColor;
    
    return finalColor;
}
```

Comment: You might find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456099/d3d11-variable-number-of-lights-in-hlsl helpful.

Comment: @Adam, thanks a lot, that is exactly what i looking for! (Load method of Texture2D)